# Django application on Heroku doesn't seem to pick up changes to static files

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am running a django app on Heroku. It is able to serve static files just fine, and when I push **new** static files to my repository they are displayed appropriately, however when I make **changes** to existing static files (e.g. CSS changes) they don't seem to be picked up.

My product stores its static files in folders called `static/` located in each of my django apps. The static root is then located in a folder called `static_root`.

When heroku performs `python manage.py collectstatic` changes to the CSS files do not seem to propagate to the `static_root` (though the correct original CSS file does exist). I tried to run `python manage.py collectstatic --clear` and the changed files were then pulled across to the `static_root`, but the server still served the old ones and *some time later the old version of the CSS files made its way back into the `static_root`*. Even when I try manually copying the changes across the old version is always the version that the server sends, and the old version sooner or later ends up in `static_root`.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

To prove that my config is correct, here is my `settings.py` and `wsgi.py`

**`settings.py`**:

```
import os
import dj_database_url


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
ROOT_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')

DEBUG = bool(int(os.getenv("DJANGO_DEBUG", 1)))
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'jumpcut', 'static_root')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'jumpcut', 'static'),
    os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'viewer', 'static'),
    os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'builder', 'static'),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'jumpcut.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'jumpcut.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'builder', 'templates'),
    os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'viewer', 'templates'),
    os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'jumpcut', 'templates'),
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # Our custom apps
    # REDACTED
)
```

**`wsgi.py`**

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "jumpcut.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling
application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

Comment: How do you make changes to your existing static files? If you make changes directly via CLI on heroku rather than pushing your changes, they'll disappear when the dynos restart. See [dynos ephemeral-filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem)

Comment: I make changes locally and push them through git, but the static_root is listed under `.gitignore`, so that could explain why the changes don't go through. Currently I try to propagate files through the heroku instance via `heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --clear`. Is that not sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution thanks to the comment by dazedconfused.

The problem was that my changes were being reverted by Heroku's [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). The solution for me was to remove my `static_root` from my `.gitignore` so Heroku takes the new static files when I push my changes.